# PowerShell: Working with the error from Standard Out (using Nessus Essentials)

Tags: powershell, nessus

```
Trying to use PowerShell to capture the running status of the "Nessus Essentials" software product.  Simply trying to capture product status: running, not running, or other.  Getting the below error each time. I've tried changing `-like` to `-match` and changing string **[warn] [scanner] Not linked to a manager** to various other shorter versions, with wildcards and without,  to no avail. I still get several lines of an ugly error message when all I want is one line with the string **Not linked to a manager** returned to console with nothing beneath that.  

Pertinent snippet working incorrectly:

    } elseif(($agentStatus.stdOut -like "[warn] [scanner] Not linked to a manager")) {
        Throw "Not linked to a manager"


The Error:
   
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The Code:
        
    Function Start-ProcessGetStreams {
    
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        Param(
            [System.IO.FileInfo]$FilePath,
            [string[]]$ArgumentList
        )
    
        $pInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        $pInfo.FileName = $FilePath
        $pInfo.Arguments = $ArgumentList
        $pInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
        $pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
        $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
        $pInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
        $pInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Hidden
    
        $proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $proc.StartInfo = $pInfo
    
        Write-Verbose "Starting $FilePath"
        $proc.Start() | Out-Null
        
        Write-Verbose "Waiting for $($FilePath.BaseName) to complete"
        $proc.WaitForExit()
    
        $stdOut = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        $stdErr = $proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        $exitCode = $proc.ExitCode
    
        Write-Verbose "Standard Output: $stdOut"
        Write-Verbose "Standard Error: $stdErr"
        Write-Verbose "Exit Code: $exitCode"
    
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "StdOut" = $stdOut
            "Stderr" = $stdErr
            "ExitCode" = $exitCode
        }
    
    }
    
    Function Get-NessusStatsFromStdOut {
        
        Param(
            [string]$stdOut
        )
        
        $stats = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
    
        $StdOut -split "`r`n" | % {
            if($_ -like "*:*") {
                $result = $_ -split ":"
                $stats.add(($result[0].Trim() -replace "[^A-Za-z0-9]","_").ToLower(),$result[1].Trim())
            }
        }
    
        Return $stats
    }
    
    Function Get-DateFromEpochSeconds {
        Param(
            [int]$seconds
        )
        
        $utcTime = (Get-Date 01.01.1970)+([System.TimeSpan]::fromseconds($seconds))
        Return Get-Date $utcTime.ToLocalTime() -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }    
    
    Try {
        $nessusExe = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles -ChildPath "Tenable\Nessus\nessuscli.exe" -ErrorAction Stop
    }  Catch {
        Throw "Cannot find NessusCli.exe"
    }
        
    Write-Host "Getting Agent Status..."
    $agentStatus = Start-ProcessGetStreams -FilePath $nessusExe -ArgumentList "managed status"
    
    If($agentStatus.stdOut -eq "" -and $agentStatus.StdErr -eq "") {
        Throw "No Data Returned from NessusCli"
    } elseif($agentStatus.StdOut -eq "" -and $agentStatus.StdErr -ne "") {
        Throw "StdErr: $($agentStatus.StdErr)"
    } elseif(($agentStatus.stdOut -like "[warn] [scanner] Not linked to a manager")) {
        Throw "Not linked to a manager"
    } elseif(-not($agentStatus.stdOut -like "*Running: *")) {
        Throw "StdOut: $($agentStatus.StdOut)"
    } else {
        $stats = Get-NessusStatsFromStdOut -stdOut $agentStatus.StdOut
        If($stats.last_connection_attempt -as [int]) { $stats.last_connection_attempt = Get-DateFromEpochSeconds $stats.last_connection_attempt }
        If($stats.last_connect -as [int]) { $stats.last_connect = Get-DateFromEpochSeconds $stats.last_connect }
        If($stats.last_scanned -as [int]) { $stats.last_connect = Get-DateFromEpochSeconds $stats.last_scanned }
    }
    
    $stats | Out-Host

Note: Code above is courtesy of [here][2], I've only made a change to the path of Nessus, and I am adding the attempt to capture that it's not connected to a manager.
```

Comment: Without wildcards, -like is really -eq.  [ is a special regex character and would have to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks, but wildcards or not, still getting a bunch more error text in the console than I need.  I'll clarify my question a bit.

Comment: Also, if the left side is an array, things work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code so that it separates standard output from error and so that it handles each line separately.

The following is how to capture standard output (excluding `else` statements and error handling) of a program (according to your `$Proc` variable)

```
if ($proc.Start())
{
    while (!$proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        $StreamLine = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()

        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($StreamLine))
        {
            # TODO: Duplicate code in this scope as needed or rewrite to use multiline regex

            $WantedLine = [regex]::Match($StreamLine, "(?<wanted>.*Not linked to a manager.*)")
            $Capture = $WantedLine.Groups["wanted"]

            if ($Capture.Success)
            {
                Write-Output $Capture.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that deal with error output separately:

```
$StandardError = $Proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($StandardError))
{
    # Or use Write-Error
    Write-Output $StandardError
}
```